# Generating Function for the sequence $ (0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},.....)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

It is connected with the logarithmic generating Function defined by:
$$ \log(1+x)=\sum_{n \ge 1}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
The sequence is being generated by $a_0=0$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$

---

**Edit:** I have used the Hint: from @Arnaud Mortier:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^n}{n}=\sum_{n \ge 1} {x^{n-1}}
$$

$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n}
$$

We know(if not p336 Concrete Mathematics)

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
we also know(if not p335) that a multiplication with $x^1$ "shifts" the generating function to the right 
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n}=x \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
Now we have:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
Now integrate both side( Now I have noticed i could have done right from the start since on page 335 there is this rule)
$$
\int_{0}^{z} G(t) dt= \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{1}{n}g_{n-1}z^n
$$

$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}x^{n-1}=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t}dt
$$
Here I am not sure
On the right side i get:
$$
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t}dt=-ln(1-x)
$$

I think some steps are obsolete, any mistakes?
The integration used the substitution: u=1-x

Comment: There's no factorial in the denominator of the coefficients!

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: There is a sequence, this sequence are the coefficients of the power series of a certain function. The exercise is to find the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ be the generating function.

Notice that your sequence satisfies $(n+1)a_{n+1} = na_n$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Multiplying this by $x^n$ and summing over $n \ge 1$ gives

$$F'(x) - a_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n = xF'(x)$$

Rearranging gives
$$F'(x) = \frac1{1-x} \implies F(x) = -\ln(1-x)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find the formal derivative of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$$
Then identify its closed form and integrate back.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this one. :)

Comment: Which function have you found? Because for me a possibility is a Dirichlet series with $s=0$.

Comment: i have made one mistake,  i am working on it, i will post it as soon its rdy

Comment: @Dog_69 i have added a solution. I dint worked with Derichlet Functions yet, but i saw the Chapter later

Comment: Yes. I think this is a better solution. Log function is a more ''common'' function than Dirichlet ones. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Hint: from @Arnaud Mortier:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^n}{n}=\sum_{n \ge 1} {x^{n-1}}
$$

$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n}
$$

We know(if not p336 Concrete Mathematics)

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
we also know(if not p335) that a multiplication with $x^1$ "shifts" the generating function to the right 
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n}=x \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
Now we have:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
Now integrate both side( Now I have noticed i could have done right from the start since on page 335 there is this rule)
$$
\int_{0}^{z} G(t) dt= \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{1}{n}g_{n-1}z^n
$$

$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}x^{n-1}=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t}dt
$$
Here I am not sure
On the right side i get:
$$
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t}dt=-ln(1-x)
$$

I think some steps are obsolete, any mistakes?
The integration used the substitution: u=1-x

Comment: That's all good.